# How to make loop calculate faster

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, while-loop, nested

I want to make this code calculate faster . My code have too much loop I want to make it less. How to minimize for loop and while loop. My code is about to Dividing English words, appearing in strings (String) text, 3 characters, and counting the frequency of three sets of characters. The function has a value of dict, where the key is a set of three characters in text, and a value is the frequency of that character in the key. Must be a word, the frequency count is Case Insensitive ('ant' and 'Ant' are cadia ) if the length is less than 3. Characters must be defined as keys such as 'a', 'in'.

```
def main():
    text = "Thank you for help me"
    print(three_letters_count(text))


def three_letters_count(text):
    d = dict()
    res = []
    li = list(text.lower().split())
    for i in li:
        if len(i) < 3:
            res.append(i)  
        while len(i) >= 3: 
            res.append(i[:3])  
            i = i[1:]
    
    for i in res:
        d[i] = res.count(i)
        
    return d
    
    



if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: What is the ultimate goal of your function. What you you expect from this?

Comment: I want to make it run faster.

Comment: I understand that, but what is the purpose of your code first. I wish to understand what you are attempting with the function before focusing on code optimisation.

Comment: Is this your expected output: {'tha': 1, 'han': 1, 'ank': 1, 'you': 1, 'for': 1, 'hel': 1, 'elp': 1, 'me': 1}`.  (just running your code).     Your goal? as it's not clear here ...

Comment: My code is about counting 3 letters to key in dict and value is frequency of 3 letter that show in res list.

Comment: Its like EX.  'eating' in my res list will have [eat,ati,ing]

Comment: and then I put it into dict if 'eat' in list have 2 my dict will be like {'eat':2}

Comment: I'd also expect "tin" in your example. The first for loop saves you the trouble of parsing the string yourself, at the cost of iterating over the string once. The while loop can be changed by slicing from some start position instead of start of string. That would save you  to repeatedly make copies of `i`. And if you'd use a hash for your `res`, you could do the counting on the fly, instead of counting afterwards.

Comment: @Ronald I don't quit understand what you are explaining.

Comment: Just look at the accepted answer. And it can be optimized even a litter better by counting on the fly. I'll post an alternative

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As promised, just an alternative to the accepted answer:

```
def main():
    text = "Thank you for help me thank you really so much"
    print(three_letters_count(text))


def three_letters_count(text):
    d = dict()
    res = {}
    li = list(text.lower().split())
    for i in li:
        if len(i) < 3:
            if (i in res):
                res[i] = res[i] + 1
            else:
                res[i] = 1  
        startpos = 0
        for startpos in range(0, len(i)):
            chunk = i[startpos:startpos + 3]
            if (chunk in res):
                res[chunk] = res[chunk] + 1
            else:
                res[chunk] = 1

    return res

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

It yields (with the modified input):

```
{'tha': 2, 'han': 2, 'ank': 2, 'you': 2, 'for': 1, 'hel': 1, 'elp': 1, 'me': 1, 'rea': 1, 'eal': 1, 'all': 1, 'lly': 1, 'so': 1, 'muc': 1, 'uch': 1}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could adjust your `while` look and switch this out for a `for` loop.

See the adjusted function below.

```
def three_letters_count(text):
    d = dict()
    res = []
    li = list(text.lower().split())
    for i in li:
        if len(i) < 3:
            res.append(i)  
        for index in range(0, len(i)):
            three_letter = i[index:index+3]
            if(len(three_letter) >= 3):
                res.append(three_letter)
    
    for i in res:
        d[i] = res.count(i)
        
    return d
```